# Java: stderr and caught exception

Tags: java, exception

I have the following method:

```
 public void doQuery(String q){
        try{
           java.sql.Statement statement.execute(q);
        } catch (SQLException e){
             System.out.println("query: "+q);
             e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
     }
```

My intention with the above was that, since occasionally the text value in the insert has a double quote which causes the statement to fail, was to catch the error and continue.

My question is, will this code do what I intend? It appears that the program is terminating due to this error -- I see a stack trace in stderr which I did not expect to see.

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: What do you think `e.printStackTrace();` is doing?

Comment: you can rather do a replace in your string q... isn't it?

Comment: this doesn't compile `java.sql.Statement statement.execute(q);` is not a valid statement [ :) ]

Comment: wrap try/ catch with `Exception` So it should be `atch (SQLException e){/**/};catch (Exception e){/**/};`

Comment: Yes, the I wanted to show the type of Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is going to do what you wanted, on any SQL exception you catch it, print the query and then print the stack trace to the error stream.

If you don't want to print it to the error stream, remove the command.

I suggest you should not print your query. This is not a good practice since potential malicious users could exploit the knowledge about your DB.

If your program terminates unexpectedly due to an unhandled exception I think your excetion is not of the type SqlException. To make sure you catch all exceptions you could define 
other catch blocks to catch more general types of Exceptions.

You could do it like this:

```
    try
    {
       java.sql.Statement statement.execute(q);
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
         System.out.println("DB Exception"); // Put breakpoint here
         e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("General Exception"); // Put breakpoint here
         e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

If you can't find the cause of the unexpected termination, you should try to debug your program. You could put breakpoints to the places highlighted, to see which one is hit. Otherwise you could just try to debug step-by-step to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks: two questions:

Comment: Thanks. I had thought that the stack trace would be printed to stdout. I think you are saying that since I am catching the Exceptionable, this is not the reason the program is terminating but I see no other reason in stderr that it is terminating. I am going to try catching Exception instead of SQLException in the catch block.

Comment: Usually it is better to handle specific types of Exceptions instead of more generic ones.

Comment: Thanks again. I did in fact check whether the exception extended SQLException and it did, so I am still puzzled.

Comment: Could you provde us more details? We can't help you much if you don't share much about the context of the problem. Please vote my answer up if you like it helped.

Comment: What other context would be helpful? The next time the program runs there will be some more information. It just occurs to me that the program is not terminating at all if this try/catch works as you say. Thanks for your help.